# Prove that $\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!}=e^{-1}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $u_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$. By Taylor Lagrange, there is a $c_{x,n}\in (0,x)$ such that $$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}+\frac{e^{c_{n,x}}}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}.$$

I will suppose that this formula hold for $x=-1$, then I get
$$|u_n-e^{-1}|=\left|\frac{e^{c_{n,-1}}}{(n+1)!}(-1)^{n+1}\right|$$
and since $e^{c_{-1,x}}\leq 1$, I get
$$|u_n-e^{-1}|\leq \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\underset{n\to\infty }{\longrightarrow }0$$
and thus $$\lim_{n\to\infty }u_n=e^{-1}.$$
**Question 1 :** Am I doing right ? is it rigorous enough ?

**Question 2 :** The problem if we are in $(x,0)$ its that $$e^0=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{e^{-x}(-x)^k}{k!}+\frac{e^{c_{n,x}}}{(n+1)!}(-)^{n+1}$$ and not $$e^x=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{x^k}{k!}+\frac{e^{c_{n,x}}}{(n+1)!}x^{n+1}.$$ I saw it doesn't matter if we are in $(x,0)$ or in $(0,x)$ but I don't understand why. But my formula is precisely $$f(b)=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(b-a)^k+\frac{f^{(n+1)}(c)}{(n+1)!}(b-a)^{n+1}$$ for a certain $c\in (a,b)$. So, how can I adapt ? Please, don't answer : "it's like that" ! I want to know how it work precisely.

Thank you.

Comment: For 1. you may want to ask your instructor. (Your argument looks good on a quick skim, so it really depends what your instructor hopes to see verified.) For 2., the issue is probably addressed in the proof of Taylor's theorem with remainder. Sometimes authors write "for $c$ in $(a, b)$" instead of "for $c$ between $a$ and $b$", with the conventional understanding that if $b < a$, they mean $b < c < a$, i.e., $c \in (b, a)$.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what facts about the exponential series you are expected to hold for true.

If you know the series for $\exp$, but not if it is an exponential function, you can start with the Cauchy-product and the theorem about it in case of absolutely convergent series
$$
\exp(x)·\exp(y)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}·\sum_{m=0}^\infty\frac{x^m}{m!}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac1{n!}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k·y^{n-k}
$$
to find $\exp(x+y)$ and thus $e·\exp(-1)=\exp(1)·\exp(-1)=\exp(0)$ which implies $\exp(-1)=1/e=e^{-1}$

---

If you start by the compound interest sequence, you might want to prove that
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}&
\left(1+\frac xn\right)^n·\left(1+\frac yn\right)^n
·\left(1-\frac{x+y}n\right)^n
\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{x+y}n+\frac{xy}{n^2}\right)^n
·\left(1-\frac{x+y}n\right)^n
\\
&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{(x+y)^2}{n^2}+\frac{xy}{n^2}-\frac{xy(x+y)}{n^3}\right)^n
\\
&=1
\end{align}
and then equally insert $x=1$, $y=-1$ where it is known that the value for $x=1$ is $e$.

Comment: Thank you. But do you agree that Taylor Lagrange says that $e^x=1+x+x^2/2+...+\frac{e^{c_x}}{n!}x^n$ **ONLY ON** $(0,x)$ and that it doesn't work on $(x,0)$ ?

Comment: You mean for $x<0$? I do not see why not. -- I think this exercise is part of the proof that you can write $\exp(x)$ as $e^x$, where the first is the series and the second the exponential function. You should check that so that you do not assume "obvious" things that are not obvious at this stage of theoretical development.